# Rerun prolog application automatically

Tags: prolog

I am designing a prolog game where i have to guess what sport the user is thinking. I have created a start *game rule and a display result (triggered after the start* game). I want the start_ game to be called automatically again right after the display result. I have created some list in the start game. am I suppose to clear the list before being able to trigger the start_ game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
main
:-
repeat ,
start_game(RESULT) ,
display_result(RESULT) ,
fail
.
```

Comment: may i ask what is the RESULT?

Comment: `RESULT` is just an place-holder for whatever gets passed from `start_game` to `display_result` .

Answer (score 2):

Why not stay in a tail-recursive loop forever - or at least until a "stop criterium" has been reached. This "stop criterium" can result directly from asking the user whether to stop or play another round.

```
game :-
   round(SomeInitialState).     % The initial state may be an empty
                                % game board for example

round(State) :-
   (stop_criterium(State))      % Should we stop? (Maybe ask the user).
   -> true                      % Yes, stop: predicate round/1 succeeds,
                                % thus ending the loop.
   ;                             % ... otherwise ...
      (play(State,NewState),    % Play a round; a new state is proposed.
       display(NewState),       % Show what's going on.
       round(NewState)).        % Then do a tail-recursive call.
                                % The new round/1 context has new state.
```

**Bonus: Using Delimited Continuations**

If you are using SWI-Prolog, you can use the disconcerting magic of [Delimited Continuations](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=delcont) together with a [global variable](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar) to store state to create an infinite loop with exit possibility like this (You don't really need the global variable, but the code [becomes much more complex without it](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/swipl_notes/about_continuations/adaptations/loop.md)):

```
game :-
   nb_setval(game_state,SomeInitialState),  % Save an initial game state to a "global variable" called "game_state"
   Goal = loop_forever(game_round),         % We will call this in reset/3
   reset(                                   % Mark this point as exit point from a shift/1 called inside "Goal" 
      Goal,                                 % Run this underneath the "reset" point
      escape(FinalState),                   % The "Ball" term matching the "escape from loop command"
      _).                                   % The continuation to get back into the loop; we don't need it.

% The "infinite loop maker"

loop_forever(Goal) :-
   call(Goal),
   loop_forever(Goal).
   
% The "action function" called from the infinite loop maker.
% N.B.: Not a loop, just a straight conjunction!

game_round :-
   nb_getval(game_state,State),     % Get the game state from a "global variable" called "game_state"
   (stop_criterium(State))          % Should we stop? (Maybe ask the user).   
    -> shift(escape(State))         % Jump out of the "infinite_goal_works(game_round)" context to the reset/3 point.
    ;  true),                       % Otherwise continue with this predicate.
   play(State,NewState),            % Play a round; a new state is proposed. 
   display(NewState),               % Show what's going on.
   nb_setval(game_state,NewState).  % Save the game state to a "global variable" called "game_state"
                                    % It will be picked up by the next activation of game_round
```

Comment: Can't `game_round` just tail-call itself in the delimited continuations case, and pass the state in an argument? If not (and even if yes, I guess) another option would be `throw`/`catch`.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Yes, it absolutely can. In fact, that would merge `loop_forever/1` and `game_round/0` into a single predicate. The above is from a demo whereby you can exchange the "loop core" which may actually be unaware that it is in a loop, hence the complexification. `throw/catch` is also ok - it's actually the same as a `shift/reset` with the `reset` not yielding a continuation (as is the case here: we just discard the continuation received from `reset`)